# Flask socketio with werkzeug DispatcherMiddleware and multiple WSGI apps: no connection

Tags: flask, websocket, subdomain, wsgi, flask-socketio

I've got a setup where I want to run multiple WSGI apps on one server and use a Flask-SocketIO socketio-server for communication in one of those apps.

I've got my WSGI-apps served via gunicorn with eventlet, as is suggested by the Flask-SocketIO manual with the following command:

`gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w 1 myapp:application`

This serves the apps all-right, the internal code for setup looks like this (`__init__.py`):

```
from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware
from Pyro4.utils.httpgateway import pyro_app as gateway

from myapp.extensions import socketio
from myapp.views.vue_js import vue
from config import PYRO_REGEX


def configure_blueprints(app):
    app.register_blueprint(vue)


def register_extensions(app):
    socketio.init_app(app)



app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True, template_folder='static', static_url_path='')
app.config.from_object('config')

configure_blueprints(app)
register_extensions(app)

# Set up WSGI application middleware to serve both the pyro httpgateway and this application
# through the same server
application = DispatcherMiddleware(gateway, {
        '/app': app
})
```

This works as it should, but my application now has no websocket connection anymore. How can I make Flask-SocketIO work in this configuration?

The problem is that the javascript connection to the socketio server is getting a 404 error when trying to connect to /socketio.

Do I need to hand the Javascript side the subdomain of my app?
How would a connection string have to look if that's the case?
Right now my connection string looks like this: `'http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/'` on the Javascript side

PS:
The reason I'm doing this is that I need to serve the Pyro4 gateway from the same domain as the rest of the application, since otherwise the browser applies same-origin-policy restrictions to my REST calls to pyro4. So if this is too convoluted, and an easier way exists to get to my end-goal, I'm also open for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some experiment with DispatchMiddleware where one of the mounts is a Flask app utilising socket.io

```
self.app.wsgi_app = DispatcherMiddleware(self.app.wsgi_app,{'/aaa/bbb':sockioapp,
 '/ccc/ddd':normalapp})
```

Here, `sockioapp` is a Flask object with SocketIO enabled, `normalapp` is not.

So the url for `sockioapp` will be `http://localhost:3000/aaa/bbb`, while the socket.io endpoint is `/socket.io`, and it couldn't make the connection (as expected) - I want to change the endpoint to `/aaa/bbb/socket.io`

For this, I added the path to Socket.IO client.

```
socket = io.connect({transports: ["websocket"], path:"/aaa/bbb/socket.io" });
```

Now the SocketIO server. I wasn't sure if I had to do this or not. I was hoping `DispatcherMiddleware` will magically add the `/aaa/bbb` path to `/socket.io`, and it appeared to be the case. So the server stays put, no need to add path.

```
socketio = SocketIO(socketioapp, host="0.0.0.0")
```

This was enough. Everything on the server side is handled magically, and no need to change the dispatcher middleware.

If you have more than one apps utilising socket.io, I think it is a good idea to have separate namespaces.

Comment: Hey @sungeunbae , I've not used this in a while now, so I can't check if your answer is actually working, but I still give you the answer mark, since it looks good, and is probably more helpful than what I've done :)

Answer (score 0):

The Socket.IO endpoint is, by default `/socket.io`. Since the first entry point of your app is the `DispatcherMiddleware`, that does not map to the application.

I have not tried this, but maybe if you add a duplicate entry for your app on the dispatcher middleware under the `/socket.io` prefix, then the Socket.IO requests will be routed to the right place.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sadly your proposal didn't work, I've "fixed" it in another way.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of fixed my problem, but sadly it's not a real fix but more of a workaround.

The reason why I had my application not on the default route was that the other wsgi-app (the pyro httpgateway) is doing some redirects itself, which led to endless redirects when I tried putting it on the `/pyro` route.

I've now modified that part of the code, and put the pyro application on the above mentioned route, while keeping my application on the main path `/`.

This allows for SocketIO to work for my main application, although as said above is more of a workaround than a complete fix.